# Prevent menu from collapsing in 768px display CSS media query

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, responsive-design

I am trying to do a site using twitter bootstrap. I am having relatively less menus, so it kind of fits within the 768px display also. But in bootstrap by default, the menu collapses using media queries. I am not able to prevent this behavior.

[image: The menu when not collapsed]

[image: Then menu collapses ones width less than 768px]

This is my html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3 logo"><h1><img src="img/logo.png" /></h1></div>
    <div class="span9">

        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
         <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
              <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Services</a> </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a> </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a> </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



    </div>
    </div>
```

I know it has something to do with the media query in bootstrap, but not able to understand.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll want to read up the section: *Using the media queries* at the bootstrap site:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive (Bootstrap 2.3.2)
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive (Bootstrap 3)

You'll want to use the relevant media queries to override the styles bootstrap adds when your viewport shrinks.

```
  // Landscape phones and down
  @media (max-width: 480px) { ... }

  // Landscape phone to portrait tablet
  @media (max-width: 768px) { ... }

  // Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) { ... }

  // Large desktop
  @media (min-width: 1200px) { .. }
```

If you don't want the navbar to collapse, remove the 'collapse' from the class name. You should probably get rid of:

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

In short, have a look over the docs, there's a section covering this exact thing titled 'Optional responsive variation' here: 
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar (Bootstrap 2.3.2)

Comment: I have the same issue, but the page in your link is not helpful. What I'm looking for is for the menu to collapse on the iPhone but not the ipad. The page doesn't explain how to do that. Any hints?

Comment: Use the media-queries - the one you want is max-width:480px. If you look at Bootstrap Responsive CSS you'll see a section such as: https://gist.github.com/2585018  . Remove the parts that change the navbar, and put them in the max-width:480px section instead.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly, you're saying to remove the collapse functionality from the `@media max-width: 768px`?

Comment: Yep, and dump it into max-width:480px. Should be kosher.

Comment: I tried this, and it sort of works. Problems: 1) the icon with the 3 little rows show up a long time before the menus disappear. 2) After the menu disappears, when you click the 3 little rows to bring it back, it will disappear again at anything less than 978px (which is where the collapse functionality is not in 768px). Any pointers?

Comment: I can't recall from the top of my head, but I'm pretty sure bootstrap add/removes the menu classes at different widths. Take at look at when the classes get added/removed in firebug (these are what is making the button display) and change them accordingly.

Comment: maks answer below is the most straightforward. Even if you are using bootstrap statically, you can change the @navbarCollapseWidth at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables and download a custom version.

Comment: Yep, Maks answer is a much better solution.

Answer (score 31):

You can customize Twitter Bootstrap css **compiling** it from sass-twitter-bootstrap scss files and setting `$navbarCollapseWidth` in `_variables.scss` to your desired value...

**Edit**

As @Accipheran stated in the comments, for Bootstrap 3.x the name of the variable you should set is `$grid-float-breakpoint`.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. I wanted the navbar to collapse for phones, but not for the iPad. This is the answer. Set `$navbarCollapseWidth` to `767px`. The iPad is 768px wide and so it won't collapse. This is the correct answer, and is much cleaner than overriding multiple media queries manually.

Comment: @emkman Sure its the best solution. Works also with LESS if you use that!

Comment: @emkman *Please* don't use 767px... not everone has iPads... Just use the pixel count you actually want, and don't cater only to iPad screens.

Comment: @DanRasmussen If you read my comment, I specifically mention the iPad for a reason. I was targeting iPads, and therefore 767px was the pixel count I actually wanted.

Comment: This is a better solution!

Comment: For bootstrap 3, the variable you need to set is `$grid-float-breakpoint`. Also, rather than going in the bootstrap source, you can just set this variable in your own css files, anywhere before the line @import "bootstrap" is called.

Answer (score 9):

This worked well for me:

```
.nav-collapse, .nav-collapse.collapse {
    overflow: visible;
}   
.navbar .btn-navbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is the proper answer. Put this into @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) and it works perfectly. No need to alter bootstrap files, and done the way bootstrap was meant to work, with overrides.

Comment: It's `.navbar-toggle` instead of `.btn-navbar` now

Comment: @SerjSagan Both options don't work for Bootstrap 3. I still get a vertical menu at a smaller size.

Answer (score 8):

Reading the answers, I believe you are talking about Bootstrap version 2. Maybe someone looking for an answer for Bootstrap 3 will arrive here. This answer is for you!

1. Go to [Bootstrap customization page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
2. redefine the @grid-float-breakpoint value for something hardcoded (e.g. 520px) or for a smaller screen size like @screen-xs-min
3. Press the button at the bottom of the page to recompile the css files
4. substitute your bootstrap.css and bootstrap-min.css files with the ones from the downloaded zip file.

Comment: What if I only want that to happen for a sub nav menu, not for the main menu? That does not seem so easy, since bootstrap itself does not (yet) have subnavs... :(

Answer (score 2):

find variable:

**@grid-float-breakpoint**

which is set to @screen-sm, you can change it according to your needs.

If you override the vendor less file, set the variable to 0px, eg:

**@grid-float-breakpoint: 0px;**

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is not have the nav collapse until it reaches a smaller value, the simplest way is to head over to the [Twitter Bootstrap customization page](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html), change the `@navbarCollapseWidth` to the value you want, and download the package.  Done.

If you want to customize beyond what this page allows, you'll have to override or customize as described in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

This example is from the official website: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

The changes are in [non-responsive.css](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css) but the important parts pertaining to `.navbar` are:

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.page-header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.page-header .lead {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely disable the collapsing navbar, add this variable in your custom LESS file:

```
@grid-float-breakpoint: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used for bootstrap 3.3.4.  It's a hack, but it's also not a 2-day fix redoing the css.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .navbar-header {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: inline-block !important;
    float: right !important;
  }
}
```

You may need to tweak the selectors, but basically, make the header full-width, then show and float the button right.

Comment: I can see 3 bar menu on the right side but the main menu is still visible. Also, the 3 bar icon doesn't click. Can somebody suggest me? I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7. Thanks.