# Bootstrap responsive menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using this wordpress theme which is built with bootstrap,
http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/
it collapses menu on ipad and iphone, but i want the menu to collapse on iphone only, not ipad. any idea how to do that?

where can i edit? is it related with css or js or both?

Comment: here is some one ask the same question check that out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094479/prevent-menu-from-collapsing-in-768px-display-css-media-query

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is preloaded with @media queries, so you will need to amend them in the core Bootstrap.css file.

press ctrl-f inside the css file and look for the below.

```css
 // Landscape phones and down
  @media (max-width: 480px) { ... }

  // Landscape phone to portrait tablet
  @media (max-width: 768px) { ... }

  // Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) { ... }

  // Large desktop
  @media (min-width: 1200px) { .. }
```

here you can change when the toggle menu kicks in.

alternatively you can filter search for "toggle" this should show you the media sections for toggle.