# About the @grid-float-breakpoint variable in BS 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In Boostrap 3 documentation I have found this:

> Customize the collapsing point
>
> Depending on the content in your navbar, you might need to change the
>   point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal
>   mode. Customize the @grid-float-breakpoint variable or add your own
>   media query.

Could I define the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable in a `main.css` file or should I generate a new customized boostrap obligatory?

Comment: @OllieCole The only thing I have tried is writing at the top of my main.css this: `@grid-float-breakpoint: 980px;` but I get an error.

Comment: `Syntax error: Invalid CSS afer "...oat-breakpoint:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " 980px;"` I'm using sass to compile my .scss

Comment: have you tried using `.grid-float-breakpoint`?

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10094479/1097752) as well for further information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@grid-float-breakpoint` is a LESS variable, you can't use it in plain CSS nor in SASS. Change the value in customizer, then download your new build.

Comment: what if this value must be decided at runtime? i.e. different devices should use different values.

Comment: @clamp Less can be [used on client-side](http://lesscss.org/#usage), but I don't see why breakpoint should be chosen at runtime.