# Using the accounts-ui-bootstrap3 package in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two issues with the Accounts-ui package in Meteor.

1. The login disappears when making the webpage smaller
2. When logged in with facebook I get a strange hashtag

This is my code:

header.html:

```
<template name="header">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SOURCEBROWSE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {{> loginButtons }}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

index.html:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
{{> header}}
</body>
```

config.js (int the server folder, my code replaced with word code):

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
        service: "facebook"
    });

    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
        service: "facebook",
        appId: "code",
        secret: "code"
    });
});
```

Screenshot:

[image: Everything working fine]

[image: dropdown accounts thing is gone]

[image: strange hashtag]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The hidden 'login' on page resize is a CSS issue - this is a responsive feature with bootstrap. When a page gets to a certain width, it changes the way pages are displayed.

You'll need to edit the bootstrap. This question, [Prevent menu from collapsing in 768px display CSS media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094479/prevent-menu-from-collapsing-in-768px-display-css-media-query) , should help you in understanding how/why bootstrap is doing this

2) The '#' tag was a coding issue with the package... https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/issues/74

You can update the mrt packages you have installed - although you might want to be wary that this could break your code! Meteorite (mrt) updates all the packages in a project and this, if you're not careful, could lead to dependency issues.

An alternative, is to create a css class that hides the element `.img-circular {display: none;}`