# Bootstrap Nav collapse disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am quite new to bootstrap. I am trying to develop quite a minimalistic site and I only got 3 menu items: my image logo, one link and one button. My menu is collapsing when using mobile which shouldn't be necessary as all three items should fit a small screen. Could someone please help me understand how I can disable the collapse but keep the menu responsive?

This is my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-  target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"/></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Kom igång</a></li>
        <li>
          <p class="navbar-btn">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="background: #D9534F; border-color: #D9534F;"><strong>Kundinlogg</strong></a>
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks alot in advance!

Jacob

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! By the look of your post, I would recommend you to have a quick look at [this page about SO's formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You used the backtick to quote your code, while normally, adding a tab to the start of your code's sentences is what does the trick. There's a `{}` button in the editor that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

--you should have to remove collapse from

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-  target=".navbar-collapse">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```

or you can use

```
.navbar-collapse, .navbar-collapse.collapse {
overflow: visible;}   
.navbar-toggle {
display: none;}
```

--also you can check This answer will help you well about disabling collapse and keeping your menu responsive 
[Prevent menu from collapsing in 768px display CSS media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094479/prevent-menu-from-collapsing-in-768px-display-css-media-query)

Comment: Hi khaledxe, thanks for the answer. I have been searching for this for days. I'm quite new at this but this exact matter seems a bit more tricky than one thinks. None of the above works. The overflow: visible and display: none just removes the menu items completely. Removing collapse just messes up the menu and still displays the toggle. There are a lot of questions on this subject but no good concrete answers. Thanks anyways!

Comment: hi jacobhed ,if you have link for this menu or snippet i can take a look and try to help you !

Comment: thanks khaledxe! I've just started getting into Less, should be easy to do this that way. I'll get back here if it doesn't work. Thanks a lot for your time!